# Getting a "java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Statement", with an open connection

Tags: java, sql, exception

I have a program that makes several requests to a database, opening and closing connections to do what it needs to do. For each connection, it does a select that return 50 results and an update; it does this roughly 10 times per connection. After that, the connection is closed, and a new one is taken. But recently we have been having some random issues in which this SQL exception appears:

java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Statement!!!

This error appears randomly. It first appeard mid-execution, and the only moment I managed to reproduce it, it happened at the initiation of the program (when I started it again after that, without making any change, it worked perfectly fine). I've looked around in the code but there's no chance that the connection closes before it can be used (the error occurs while inserting a parameter in a prepared statement). I'm already using c3p0 to manage the connection pool, so I don't know where else to look.

Someone has faced this error before? Any suggestions on where to look or how to reproduce it so I can test it properly?

Edit: Here is the problematic piece of code

```
    try{
        //send row to producer
        producer.processItem(fields);

        if (stmtLasProcessedTransaction == null) {
            stmtLasProcessedTransaction = getDbConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE JTICKET_SUBSCRIBER SET LAST_PROCESSED_ROW = ? WHERE NAME = ? ");
            logger.trace("creating statement");
        }
        //update last processed transaction
        logger.trace("Setting the primary key to the prepared statement");
        stmtLasProcessedTransaction.setString(1, primaryKey);
        logger.trace("Setting the name to the prepared statement");
        stmtLasProcessedTransaction.setString(2, name);
        logger.trace("Attempting to execute the update on JTICKET_SUBSCRIBER in consumer {}",this.name);
        stmtLasProcessedTransaction.executeUpdate();
        logger.trace("Commiting execution");
        getDbConnection().commit();
        logger.trace("Update on JTICKET_SUBSCRIBER in consumer {} executed successfully",this.name);

        if (processedRows % 500 == 0) {
            logger.trace("resetting prepared statement");
            stmtLasProcessedTransaction.close();
            logger.trace("statement closed");
            stmtLasProcessedTransaction = null;
        }
        processedRows++;

    }catch(SQLException sqlException){
        logger.error("An SQL error ocurred while processing consumed item. Closing database connection and statement",sqlException);
        try{
            stmtLasProcessedTransaction.close();
            logger.info("Previous prepared statement of db consumer {} closed",this.name);
        }catch(Throwable throwable){
            logger.info("Couldn't properly close the prepared statement of db consumer {}",this.name);
        }finally{
            stmtLasProcessedTransaction=null;
        }

        try{
            databaseConnection.rollback();
            logger.info("Rollback of db connection of consumer {} done successfully",this.name);
            databaseConnection.close();
            logger.info("Previous connection of db consumer {} closed",this.name);
        }catch(Throwable throwable){
            logger.info("Couldn't rollback and/or close the connection of db consumer {}",this.name);
        }finally{
            databaseConnection=null;
        }
        throw sqlException;
    }catch(Exception exception){
        logger.error("An error ocurred while processing consumed item.", exception);
        throw exception;
    }
```

The prepared statement is a local variable, not a function one, so it can be re-used with every loop (this piece is part of a function that is called once for every result in a query that is done with a prepared statement to the same db connection). The error occurs when I'm trying to work on the prepared statement.

And the latest stack:

> > 18/06/15 15:54:34.841 [ecbcbcmt] TRACE DatabaseConsumer - creating statement 18/06/15 15:54:34.850 [ecbcbcmt] ERROR DatabaseConsumer - An
> >     error ocurred while processing consumed item. java.sql.SQLException:
> >     You can't operate on a closed Statement!!!    at
> >     com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
> >     ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar:0.2.9]   at
> >     com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
> >     ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar:0.2.9]   at
> >     com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setString(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:488)
> >     ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]   at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.database.DatabaseConsumer.processRow(DatabaseConsumer.java:152)
> >     [bin/:na]     at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.database.DatabaseNumberConsumer.processRows(DatabaseNumberConsumer.java:73)
> >     [bin/:na]     at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.database.DatabaseConsumer.start(DatabaseConsumer.java:65)
> >     [bin/:na]     at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:35)
> >     [bin/:na]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_38-ea]
> >     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null   at
> >     com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setString(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:482)
> >     ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]   ... 5 common frames omitted 18/06/15
> >     15:54:34.852 [ecbcbcmt] WARN  DatabaseConsumer - An error ocurred
> >     while consuming table data. DatabaseConsumer will be restarted.
> >     java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Statement!!!     at
> >     com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
> >     ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar:0.2.9]   at
> >     com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
> >     ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar:0.2.9]   at
> >     com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setString(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:488)
> >     ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]   at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.database.DatabaseConsumer.processRow(DatabaseConsumer.java:152)
> >     ~[bin/:na]    at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.database.DatabaseNumberConsumer.processRows(DatabaseNumberConsumer.java:73)
> >     ~[bin/:na]    at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.database.DatabaseConsumer.start(DatabaseConsumer.java:65)
> >     ~[bin/:na]    at
> >     us.inswitch.jticket.subscriber.consumer.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:35)
> >     [bin/:na]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_38-ea]
> >     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null   at
> >     com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setString(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:482)
> >     ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]   ... 5 common frames omitted

It's weird because it's completely random. We've had the program up and running for a while now, with all the connections working perfectly fine, and we get this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you share the problematic code please? It's a bit hard to answer the question with so little details.

Comment: Probably the connection is shared between processes, and one of the process closes the connection while another is still using it, but this will be very odd and cannot be confirmed unless we have a thread dump or see the design of the code to do a further evaluation.

Comment: @katVolkov are you closing the resources like connection, preparedstatements, etc in finally block? Such weird issue may occur if you do not close the resources gracefully.

Comment: Kindly share Exception Stack, someone might be able to help you. You may match yours in [c3p0 bugs](http://sourceforge.net/p/c3p0/bugs/)

Comment: Just posted the piece of code and the latest stack. Also, I believe that every db related operation is closed inside a try-catch-finally, in a proper way (with the exception of a couple of small querys that are closed immediately after executing, but we didn't feel that they really needed to be closed that gracefully)

Comment: Very similar situation here. We went over the code many times to verify proper nesting, resp. try-with-resources for opening/closing connection/statement/result. We are also using c3p0. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry Harald, but I can't even remember this problem. It's been too long ago :c

Answer (score 1):

Use local variables, or otherwise use PreparedStatements carefully.
This avoids concurrent usage as in a web application.

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ...
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        ...
    } // rs close
} // Does stm.close()
```

The try-with-resources also closes when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The statement stmtLasProcessedTransaction.close(); is present at two places which is fishy!!
1. within try block in conditional if
2. within catch block

Better programming practice is to have only one close statement, that too in finally block

PS: You can have try-catch-finally within finally block as well